# What is Prarabdha?

Tags: karma

1. What is Prarabdha?
2. Who defines our Prarabdha?
3. Is our Prarabdha pre-defined?
4. Are we doing our Karmas based on our Prarabdha?
5. Are we accumulating our Prarabdha based on our positive or negative karmas?
6. Is Karma or Prarabdha the same?
7. How do one comes to know of his Prarabdha?
   Please do provide more details related with Prarabdha.

Comment: Astrology gives effects of only Prarabda Karma in this life. To know your Prarabda Krama exactly, you should realize your self (atma) or only a sage can tell you your Prarabda Karama.

Comment: Prarabdha means that karma which has already begun to blossom. i.e. Think of karma as an arrow. The arrow that has not yet left the bow is not prarabdha. However if the arrow has already left the bow, then it HAS to HIT a Target. That is prarabdha. That karma has already begun to come after you, thus it cannot be stopped. There are only four ways to remove prarabdha, 1. Absolute Self-Knowledge (Jnana) 2. Absolute self-surrender (Atma Nivedanam) 3. Total eradication of selfishnesss  (Variagya) or 4. Grace of God or Guru or another Saint who will take upon Himself your prarabdha. All the best.